# Ошибка при подключении django к postgreSQL в docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psycopg2

Запускаю 2 сервиса на docker-compose. Django - на 8000 порту, postgres - на 5432. В настройках БД в django указан тот же порт - 5432:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "our_site",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "admin",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}
```

Postgres запускается нормально, лог:

```
database system is ready to accept connections
```

а django с ошибкой:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY req.txt .

RUN pip install -r req.txt

EXPOSE 8000

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver" ]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build: ./our_site
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Адаптер к БД - psycopg2-binary==2.9.5

Answer (score 0):

Доавить `network_mode: host` в docker-compose.yml для подключения к localhost:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build: ./our_site
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    network_mode: host
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Либо подключатся к базе данных указав в Django `"HOST": "db"`