# Ошибка при подключении django к postgreSQL в docker-compose

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker-compose

При запуске сервисов из docker-compose Django - на 8000 порту, postgres - на 5432 выходит ошибка

```
postgres_db | Initializing datadir...
postgres_db | Initializing certdir...
postgres_db | Initializing logdir...
postgres_db | Initializing rundir...
postgres_db | Setting resolv.conf ACLs...
postgres_db | Initializing database...
admin_bot_django | /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py:158: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': connection to server at "postgres" (192.168.48.2), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
admin_bot_django |  Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
admin_bot_django | 
admin_bot_django |   warnings.warn(
admin_bot_django | No changes detected
postgres_db | Configuring hot standby...
postgres_db | ‣ Setting postgresql.conf parameter: wal_level = 'hot_standby'
postgres_db | ‣ Setting postgresql.conf parameter: max_wal_senders = '16'
postgres_db | ‣ Setting postgresql.conf parameter: checkpoint_segments = '8'
postgres_db | ‣ Setting postgresql.conf parameter: wal_keep_segments = '32'
admin_bot_django | Traceback (most recent call last):
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
admin_bot_django |     self.connect()
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
admin_bot_django |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
admin_bot_django |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
admin_bot_django |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
admin_bot_django |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
admin_bot_django |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
admin_bot_django |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
admin_bot_django |     connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
admin_bot_django |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
admin_bot_django |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
admin_bot_django |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django | psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "postgres" (192.168.48.2), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
admin_bot_django |  Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
admin_bot_django | 
admin_bot_django | 
admin_bot_django | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
admin_bot_django | 
admin_bot_django | Traceback (most recent call last):
admin_bot_django |   File "/src/django_app.py", line 3, in <module>
admin_bot_django |     main()
admin_bot_django |   File "/src/admin_bot_django/manage.py", line 18, in main
admin_bot_django |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
admin_bot_django |     utility.execute()
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
admin_bot_django |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
admin_bot_django |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
admin_bot_django |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
admin_bot_django |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 106, in wrapper
admin_bot_django |     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
admin_bot_django |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 117, in handle
admin_bot_django |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
admin_bot_django |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
admin_bot_django |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
admin_bot_django |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
admin_bot_django |     self.build_graph()
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
admin_bot_django |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
admin_bot_django |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
admin_bot_django |     if self.has_table():
admin_bot_django |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
admin_bot_django |     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
admin_bot_django |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
admin_bot_django |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
admin_bot_django |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
admin_bot_django |     return self._cursor()
admin_bot_django |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
admin_bot_django |     self.ensure_connection()
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
admin_bot_django |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
admin_bot_django |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 288, in ensure_connection
admin_bot_django |     with self.wrap_database_errors:
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
admin_bot_django |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
admin_bot_django |     self.connect()
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
admin_bot_django |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
admin_bot_django |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
admin_bot_django |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
admin_bot_django |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
admin_bot_django |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
admin_bot_django |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
admin_bot_django |     connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
admin_bot_django |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
admin_bot_django |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
admin_bot_django |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
admin_bot_django | django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "postgres" (192.168.48.2), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
admin_bot_django |  Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
admin_bot_django |
```

Настройки БД в django:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "DB_NAME",
        "USER": "DB_USER",
        "PASSWORD": "DB_PASS",
        "HOST": "postgres",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'
volumes:
  pgdata:

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_db
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:latest
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: $DB_NAME
      POSTGRES_USER: $DB_USER
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $DB_PASS
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U democrat -d new_db_democrat" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s
    networks:
      - botnet
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/var/log
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - .:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  django:
    container_name: admin_bot_django
    build:
      context: .
    command: sh start_django.sh
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - botnet
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Единственное что я нашел это [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499892/Ошибка-при-подключении-django-к-postgresql-в-docker](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499892/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-django-%D0%BA-postgresql-%D0%B2-docker) , но я уже это делаю указав в качестве `"HOST": "postgres"`. Если запускать Django и postgres на сервере вне docker-compose все отлично запускается без ошибок. Я новичок и плохо разбираюсь в этом. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а постгря поднята?

Comment: Да конечно все поднято.